# curl POST and GET response

Tags: linux, curl, command-line-interface

I'm trying to write a simple one-liner that will take a .crt and pass it to the CRT checker as SSLShopper.com. I can POST the data, but all I get back is headers and the HTTP response. The form on their site seems simple enough, just an AJAX call that returns the result. This is what I have so far:

```
curl -L -i -X POST -k "https://www.sslshopper.com/assets/snippets/sslshopper/ajax/ajax_decode.php" --data-binary @test.crt
```

Is there any way to POST and GET at the same time?

Comment: HTTP is based on "state". You make a request or post and get back a response. One thing at a time. That's just how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to send the data in form-url-encoded format with following parameters :

- `cert_text={CERT_CONTENT}`
- `decode_type=certificate`

You need also `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` & `Connection: keep-alive` headers :

```bash
cert_content=$(cat test.crt)
curl 'https://www.sslshopper.com/assets/snippets/sslshopper/ajax/ajax_decode.php' \
    -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
    -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
    --data-urlencode "cert_text=$cert_content" \
    --data-urlencode "decode_type=certificate"
```

But for this task, you don't need to call some endpoint to check a certificate, as it's specified in https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html, you can use [openssl](/questions/tagged/openssl) directly :

```
openssl x509 -in test.crt -noout -subject -enddate -startdate -issuer -serial
```

Comment: Thank you, your curl method worked. You're right I could use the cli version but it spits out a lot more info than I was looking for. I am comparing both versions to see which one is easier to sed to extract the info I need.

Comment: @MattMorrow if you want only the subject you can use : `openssl x509 -in test.crt  -noout -subject`

Comment: @MattMorrow I've updated with `openssl` cmd that request the same data  as does the http request, just pick the field you need